# How to handle prompt in Docker Exec

Tags: docker, exec, nextcloud

I try to execute the following line:

```
docker exec --user www-data nextcloud_docker php /var/www/html/occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

which returns a prompt:

```
This can take up to hours, depending on the number of files in your instance!
Continue with the conversion (y/n)? [n]
```

Unfortunately the docker exec command ends (returns to shell) and I am not able to start the occ command.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the `-i` flag on the docker command and piping a 'y' into it, like this

```
echo y | docker exec -i --user www-data nextcloud_docker php /var/www/html/occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

or you can run the command fully interactively with the `-it` flags like this

```
docker exec -it --user www-data nextcloud_docker php /var/www/html/occ db:convert-filecache-bigint
```

Comment: That did not work. It still returns to the shell.

Comment: You can try to run it fully interactive like I've added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

occ has a `-n` switch.
I run it from cron, including the update. I have these lines in /home/update-nextcloud-inside-container.sh inside my container:
`#!/bin/bash`

date

```
sed -i 's~www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin~www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash~g' /etc/passwd

su -c "cd /var/www/nextcloud; php /var/www/nextcloud/updater/updater.phar --no-interaction" www-data

su -c "cd /var/www/nextcloud; ./occ db:add-missing-indices -n" www-data

su -c "cd /var/www/nextcloud; ./occ db:convert-filecache-bigint -n" www-data

sed -i s~www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash~www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin~g /etc/passwd
```

and the host cron launches a script with these lines:

```
ActiveContainer=$(/home/myusername/bin/lsdocker.sh | grep next )

docker exec -i ${ActiveContainer} /home/update-nextcloud-inside-container.sh
```

I see now I am missing taking the instance off-line for running `convert-filecache`. I'll have to add that.

Edit: (`lsdocker.sh` is a script that uses docker ps to list just the active container names)